# Load gif from network url android using fresco library

Tags: android, animated-gif, lottie, fresco

I am able to keep GIF file in drawable folder and use :

```
fun showGif(gifView: SimpleDraweeView?, resourceId: Int) {
    val draweeController: DraweeController = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
        .setUri(UriUtil.getUriForResourceId(resourceId))
        .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
        .build()
    gifView?.controller = draweeController
}
```

call it like :

```
 showGif(binding.mic, R.drawable.mic_recording)
```

Now the GIF file is  https://lottiefiles.com/share/gordjiyb, the downloaded GIF size is 600kb.
There is another way to keep JSON file which is 20 kb, I tried loading with Lottie and it worked, but With fresco library haven't found a solution.
I tried loading URL by this method :

```
fun showGif(myDraweeView: SimpleDraweeView?, uri: String) =
    myDraweeView?.apply {
        controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
            .setUri(uri)
            .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
            .build()
    }
```

I tried passing https://lottiefiles.com/share/gordjiyb and other examples URLs to this method, but it does not work.

***I want to load GIF through URL only with fresco library, is it possible?
Please let me know If you have achieved this.***

I have seen it working with GLIDE and LOTTIEs, but I have fresco used it in the app already, so we want to use only this library.

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable animated GIF support for Fresco, you have to add the following Gradle dependency to your app:

```
// For animated GIF support
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'
```

as described here: https://frescolib.org/docs/